# Can anyone identify this trans-neon green piece?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I've got two of these little fellas in my mixed box circa 2000. No markings and no ideas!

*Dish 2 x 2 Inverted for reference.*

*edit, added *Antenna Whip 8H* for another reference

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think those are Lego parts.

Comment: Yeah, but the spherical tip looks a lot like [Antenna whip 8H](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2569#T=C). I'd like to see the mystery side by side with such an antenna, to see if the dimensions match.

Comment: I've gone through the [list of parts available in trans-neon green](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?colorPart=16&catType=P) and haven't found a match.

Comment: @IvanSanchez they match; same dimensions. Pic attached. Same tips, I haven't a clue, bricklink has been no help.

Comment: I suspect this might be a prototype of some sort. You may want to post in this [Flickr group](https://flickr.com/groups/rarelego/pool/). There's a lot of rare/non-production stuff posted and group members are quite knowledgeable.

Comment: Does the strange end offer any connection possibilities with other LEGO pieces?

Answer (score 9):

This appears to not be a Lego piece at all, but rather part T250 of the [509 Odyssey Transporter marble elevator made by Toto Toys](https://tototoys.com.hk/product/509-odyssey/).

See also [this eBay listing](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/134801902815) for spare parts for the elevator, including this piece.

[image: Photo from eBay listing]

Also included in part list:

[image]